# RFI, looking for documentation on Authentication and Authorisation in Symfony

Tags: php, authentication, symfony-1.4

I've scanned through the symfony books available on the symfony site and googled (although not extensively) but can't find any useful information on securing a symfony site and locking down access to only allow authenticated users.

I'm new to PHP and symfony so I'm looking for something that doesn't assume too much prior knowledge, a tutorial would be perfect.

Please can anyone provide any links to things I might find useful?

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [sfGuardPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfGuardPlugin) that is the official plugin for autentication and authorization. Check the [Jobeet Example](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/13#chapter_13_application_security) that explains how to use it with doctrine.

Comment: Thanks, I've had a bit of time to do more searching and found the sfDoctrineGuardPlugin as I'm working with that ORM